# C# memory type bigger than ulong

Tags: c#, math

I need to do huge power calculations (think 2 ^ 1,000,000) in C#, and a ulong is nowhere near sufficient. There's probably not anything bigger implemented in the .NET, but is there some 3rd party thing, or even something I can make that will work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using the .NET Framework 4.0, you can use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). Just add a reference to the `System.Numerics` assembly.

There are plenty of other implementations as well if the .NET Framework 4.0 isn't available to you, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx) on CodeProject.

Comment: Wow, never knew about this. Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` from .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

The term for what you appear to be looking for is "arbitrary precision arithmetic" and, in the case of 2^1,000,000, an arbitrary precision integer.

System.Numeric.BigIntegers in .NET 4 will likely work fine.

If you need to use an earlier version of .NET or any other language, or need more features or performance, the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/) is the usual stop for uncommon math. GMP is written in C and is available through wrappers for just about any other language.